# Assign value to a field after form submission cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have an Event model that in a database has two fields to store pause time, namely *'phour'* and *'pmin'*.
In an Event creation form I have input fields of type time that produce the following array after the form is submitted:

```
array(
    'Event' => array(

        'pause' => array(
            'hour' => '02',
            'min' => '30'
        ),
        'hours' => '3',
        'minutes' => '30',
    )
)
```

I need to assign the pause hours and minutes to the according DB fields after the form is submitted, but I just cannot get it to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please paste the code from the view

Comment: What are you DB fields? You could save that directly to your DB as `$this->Even->save($this->request->data)`... However, you would need to have the correct fields to handle it. Is `pause` a field in DB. Perhaps you need to concat these 2 values... like `pause` = `hour` + `min`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use the **beforeSave()** callbacks in your model for edit your data.

See [Callbacks Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html)

With the example of @jimmy-madon

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['phour'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['pause']['hour'];
        $this->data[$this->alias]['pmin'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['pause']['min'];

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: $this->data['Event'] should be $this->data[$this->alias]. Except that this answer is the better one because it's doing it in the right place.

Comment: I agree to both @burzum and @Jose Ayram. However, the 'pause' key might not always be passed like that, so would be helpful to change the condition to `if (!empty($this->data['Event']['pause']) {` or `if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['pause']) {`

Answer (score 0):

In the action called by your form, use:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['Event']) {
    $this->request->data['Event']['phour'] = $this->request->data['Event']['pause']['hour'];
    $this->request->data['Event']['pmin'] = $this->request->data['Event']['pause']['min'];
    $this->Event->save($this->request->data);
}
```

Comment: @Domas Your code edit was correct and should've been accepted. I have incorporated the change. Sorry I missed that.